# what is $e^{ix}$ as $x \to \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

What is the value of the following?

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-ix}$$

I have looked at a few criteria for convergence, such as the simple ratio test, or the integral test.

In this case the expression $e^{ix}$ rotates around a unit circle as $x$ grows.

Comment: It doesn't exist.

Comment: Is $x$ real, imaginary, or complex?

Comment: The tests you mention pertain to infinite sums...it isn't clear how you intend to apply them to this problem.

Comment: @TariqRashid Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

Yes it "rotates clockwise around a unit circle" as $x$ grows and therefore the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: (+1) Sorry about the edit, I edited consistently with the title, which is inconsistent with the main body.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier You are welcome! Thanks