# Prove that: $\int_0^{\infty}\sin x\, dx=1$ and $\int_0^{\infty}\cos x\,dx=0.$

Tags: improper-integrals

Recently I was solving some problems on *Fourier transform* and in one of the problems I encountered the following integral:$$\int_0^{\infty}\cos x\,dx.$$ Surely the integral does not converge and also they are not Riemann integrable, according to me. Then I searched for it online and found out the two results mentioned in title. But the proof was done by Complex analysis. I haven't studied Complex analysis yet so was unable to understand those proofs. But seeing those proofs I got an idea to evaluate the integrals as follows:$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-ix}\,dx=\frac1{-i}\Big[e^{-ix}\Big]_0^{\infty}=-i.$$Thus comparing real and imaginary parts,  we have:$\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}\cos x\,dx=0$ and $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}\sin x\, dx=1.$

**Is this a proper approach?**

[Another approach which I could think of, uses the following property of *Laplace Transform*:

If $\mathscr{L}\{f(t)\}=\bar f(s).$ Then $$\int_0^{\infty}\bar f(s)\,ds=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{f(t)}t\, dt.$$ Letting $f(t)=t\sin t$ yeilds $\int_0^{\infty}\sin t\,dt=1$ and letting $f(t)=t\cos t$ yeilds $\int_0^{\infty}\cos t\, dt=0.$]

Comment: How did you evaluate $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}x}$?

Comment: What makes you conclude that $e^{-ix}$ tends to zero as $x \to \infty$?

Comment: For every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $|e^{-ix}|=1$, so there is no way the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{-ix}$ is equal to $0$.

Comment: Yes, got it. Thank you everyone. I completely missed the fact which all of you have pointed out above.

Comment: The integrals don't converge tho

Answer (score 5):

By inserting a factor $e^{-\lambda x},$ where $\lambda>0,$ the integrals can be made convergent. The results will be analytical expressions in terms of $\lambda,$ which are valid also for $\lambda=0.$

For the cosine integral we get
$$\begin{align}
C(\lambda)
&:= \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x} \cos x \, dx \\
&= \left[ e^{-\lambda x} \sin x \right]_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty (-\lambda e^{-\lambda x}) \sin x \, dx \\
&= \lambda \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x} \sin x \, dx \\
&= \lambda \left( \left[ e^{-\lambda x} (-\cos x) \right]_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty (-\lambda e^{-\lambda x}) (-\cos x) \, dx \right) \\
&= \lambda \left( 1 - \lambda\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x} \cos x \, dx \right) \\
&= \lambda \left( 1 - \lambda C(\lambda) \right) \\
\end{align}$$

Thus $C(\lambda) = \frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda^2}$ so $C(0) = 0.$

Likewise, for the sine integral we get
$$\begin{align}
S(\lambda)
&:= \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x} \sin x \, dx \\
&= \left[ e^{-\lambda x} (-\cos x) \right]_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty (-\lambda e^{-\lambda x}) (-\cos x) \, dx \\
&= 1 - \lambda \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x} \cos x \, dx \\
&= 1 - \lambda \left( \left[ e^{-\lambda x} \sin x \right]_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty (-\lambda e^{-\lambda x}) \sin x \, dx \right) \\
&= 1- \lambda^2 \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x} \sin x \, dx \\
&= 1 - \lambda^2 S(\lambda) \\
\end{align}$$
Thus, $S(\lambda) = \frac{1}{1+\lambda^2}$ so $S(0) = 1.$

Comment: I think it's valid for $\lambda \gt 0$ not  $\lambda = 0$. As improper riemann integral $\int_0^{\infty}\sin x\, dx$ and $\int_0^{\infty}\cos x\, dx$ are divergent. Only if $\lambda \gt 0$ we have $e^{-\lambda x} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: @S.H.W. Yes, the integrals are only valid for $\lambda > 0$ but the expression found is analytical in $\lambda$ and also defined for $\lambda = 0.$ We define the integrals with $\lambda=0$ by [analytic continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation).

Comment: Oh, I see. Unfortunately I haven't studied analytic continuation yet. Thanks for clarification. Nice answer(+1).

Comment: interesting answer (+1)

Comment: Thank you sir. Got it...

Comment: @md2perpe, Sir, if I'm not wrong then here we're actually evaluating $\mathscr L\{\cos t\}\left(=\frac s{s^2+1}\right)$ and $\mathscr L\{\sin t\}\left(=\frac1{s^2+1}\right)$. Isn't it? (where $\Re(s)>0$)

Comment: @DhrubajyotiBhattacharjee. Yes, I realized that. But our goal is not one usually associated with the Laplace transform, but to give meaning to the divergent integrals.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-ix}$$doesn't exist. You can see that using $e^{-ix} = -i\sin(x) + \cos (x)$. Increasing $x$ rotates the point $P(\cos x , -\sin x)$ around a unit circle. Alternatively, let $x = n\pi$ then $e^{-i x} = (-1)^n$ and this is a divergent sequence. Some related questions: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2940303/e-it-as-t-approaches-infinity) , [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2818816/what-is-eix-as-x-to-infty) and [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2212798/complex-limit-of-an-exponential).

We should use the generalized Fourier transform in the case of $f(x) = \cos(2\pi a x)$ and $g(x) =\sin(2\pi a x)$ because as improper Riemann integral, the integrals are divergent.

Let $$\mathcal{F}\{f(x)\} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-2\pi i sx}dx$$So we have $$\mathcal{F}\{\cos(2\pi a x)\} = \mathcal{F}\{\frac{e^{2\pi i x a} + e^{-2\pi i x a}}{2}\} = \frac{1}{2}(\delta(s-a) + \delta(s+a))$$It is true in the sense of distributions. For complete explanation, refer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2650632/is-there-a-difference-between-the-fourier-transform-on-a-distribution-and-on-a-f) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1428608/why-fourier-transform-is-tempered-distribution).

Comment: Haven't read generalized Fourier transform yet. So need to read it first. BTW is it related to Laplace transform? I mean, we can consider Laplace transform as a generalization of Fourier transform no?

Comment: @DhrubajyotiBhattacharjee No it's different from that. You can see this for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)

Comment: @DhrubajyotiBhattacharjee Also I recommend this great lectures as a starting point: https://www.amazon.com/Lectures-Fourier-Transform-Applications-Undergraduate/dp/1470441918

Comment: Oh ok sir. Thank you so much.

Comment: @DhrubajyotiBhattacharjee You're welcome. I've added some details.